# Can I always guarantee/assume another i.i.d random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let $X_1$ be given as a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Can we always guarantee the existence of i.i.d (independent and identically distributed) random variables $X_2$, $X_3$, $\cdots$  on the same space? If so, how...?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: A little too abstract, but very interesting. Perhaps they may exist but be unachievable. Consider $X$ to be the number of years in prison given to a person, bribing the Chief Justice in some fixed country. That you have $X_1$ since someone did it and got caught, does not imply you will ever have other elements in your sample.

Comment: In Shiryaev's Probability, it is often assumed that the probability space is "sufficiently large" so that iid $X_i$ exist. I'd look there for more details.

Comment: If there exists a sequence of i.i.d. non-degenerate random variables $X_1, X_2, \cdots $ on  $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, then we must have $|\Omega| \geq |\mathbb{R}|$. Saying differently, any $\Omega$ with $|\Omega| < |\mathbb{R}|$ cannot host such a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider for example $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{3}$, $\mathcal{F}=2^\Omega$, and
$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}.$$
Suppose $X_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ are i.i.d. Then
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=0,\dots,X_n=0)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(X_i=0)=1/2^n.$$
However, we also have
$$|\Omega|\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1=0,\dots,X_n=0)=|\{X_1=0,\dots,X_n=0\}|\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
Thus $|\Omega|/2^n=1/2^{n-3}\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $n\le 3$. Thus given $X_1\sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ in this case, we can only construct at most $3$ i.i.d. variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Then, could we always assume that two i.i.d. random variables in every probability space?

Comment: @withgrace1040 Nope. Do the exact same example with $\Omega=\{0,1\}$.